# c# ListView Column and items different alignment

Tags: c#, listview

Is these possible that in listview column header will be align center and the item of that column will be align right.

For example

```
Column1 | Column2
item11 | item12
item21 | item22
```

I want the Column2 will align center and the (item12 and item22) will align right.

Answer (score 0):

In a HeaderColumns or in Items in this colums you can try use ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign and ItemStyle-VerticalAlign.

Comment: <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />

as

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="uname" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="uname" HeaderText="uname" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="uname">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
               
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
You can try do something like that.

Comment: hehe. btw is not asp is just C# windows form.

Comment: This code will set your item in your Columns will be "MiddleCenter"
This is code in Forms Designer when you create a DatagridView and you change DataGridViewCellStyle.
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
this.Columns1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
this.Columns1.HeaderText = "Column1";

Btw you can do this with your headercolumns with DefaultHeaderCellType
I`m so sorry, I can't find how to design view my code in this. It always in a line.

Comment: It is not also "datagridview" it is "ListView"

Comment: OMG :)) I nerver use ListView in C# WindownForm.
Btw I see in Properties of this ListView have "TextAlign" when you Edit a Columns. Have you try to do that ?
Sr about my English. Itn't good